# Implement an internal regex tester

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers

Anyone who spends any time in the [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) tag knows that a lot of answers will usually include a link to an online tester. I have also seen the implementation of snippets to be very helpful when related to HTML, CSS, etc.

The tester could use the questions tags to get the flavour of regex to use and/or use HTML comments.

This will also reduce the amount of external links in questions/answers and that is always a good thing.

Can this be implemented?

---

Before anyone says it I know that this is a mammoth task but, at least I believe, this will be highly useful for questions and answers including regex.

Comment: That's *far harder* than a HTML / CSS / JS snippet editor. Browser don't provide a wide range of regex implementations.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Which is why I put the "mammoth task" bit

Comment: With new features, you always have to balance implementation effort with usefulness. In this case, I doubt the usefulness is high enough to justify the higher implementation effort.

Comment: Also, the problem snippets solved where that people would post the code *only on jsfiddle* and not on SO. That's hardly the case with regexes. Why re-invent the regex tester wheel when regex101.com does such a great job without draining the example out of SO posts?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't doubt that the implementation cost would be more than the rewards, at least initially. And it isn't but it should hopefully make people posting questions, and answers, provide more samples which is a major problem with most regex questions I see. They are usually of the form of "I have this string and need to match this". However, with an internal tester it might encourage them to show more input vs expected output test cases

Comment: @MartijnPieters Essentially snippets re-invented the wheel but at the same time solved a problem for SO.

Comment: I highly doubt a regex tester would lead to better questions, to be honest. The issue with regex questions is that people don't have the faintest clue as  to how to write a regex in the first place.

Comment: @Martijn Not disagreeing, but the same could be said for a great many askers of HTML, CSS, JS questions...

Comment: @TinyGiant: and did you see an improvement in the quality of those questions when snippets where introduced?

Comment: @Martijn Only in what you mentioned previously: more users include code in their questions, but only a marginal difference.

Answer (score 3):

No as not enough value.

For many languages there is problem of not providing code in question or answer which is partially solved by providing syntax highlighting/snippets on SO. I don't see such problem with regular expression - even the lowest quality questions and answers provide "code" inline in the answer.

Automatic parsing of a regular expression would be nice, but one need to add text explaining why particular constructs are used anyway - so only minor benefit there too.